# Draw trajectory in Carla using Pygame windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, draw, carla

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to create a trajectory visualization in a Pygame window, similar to the image shown below:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMFGf.png)

The concept behind this is to retrieve waypoints from Carla, and then draw a trajectory on the Pygame window. The trajectory should extend from the vehicle's current location to a specific point. This trajectory should also update dynamically as the vehicle moves.

her's what i did

```
    from cameraManager import CameraManager, HUD
    import carla
    import pygame
    import numpy as np
    import random

 # Initialize CARLA
 client = carla.Client('localhost', 2000)
 client.set_timeout(2.0)
 world = client.get_world()


 # Pygame initialization
 pygame.init()
 # Define the font for the text
 pygame.font.init()
 font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 36)
 display_width, display_height = 800, 600

 display = pygame.display.set_mode(
    (display_width, display_height),
    pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
 pygame.display.set_caption('Waypoints Visualization')

 clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 hud = HUD(display_width, display_height)


 def spawn_vehicle():
    """
    This function spawns vehicles at the given spawn points. 
    It search for a random point that not taken by another vehicle or object
    """
    world = client.get_world()
    blueprint_library = world.get_blueprint_library()
    vehicle_bp = blueprint_library.find('vehicle.audi.a2')

    # Set a different spawn point manually
    spawn_point = carla.Transform(carla.Location(
        x=0, y=0, z=0), carla.Rotation(yaw=0))

    while True:
        try:
            vehicle = world.spawn_actor(vehicle_bp, spawn_point)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Spawn failed: {e} Retrying with a different spawn point")
            # Generate a new spawn point
            spawn_points = world.get_map().get_spawn_points()
            spawn_point = random.choice(spawn_points)
            print(f"Spawn point: {spawn_point}")

    return vehicle







 def get_waypoints_ahead(vehicle):
    current_map = world.get_map()
    waypoint = current_map.get_waypoint(
        vehicle.get_location(), project_to_road=True, lane_type=carla.LaneType.Driving)

    waypoints = []
    for _ in range(8//2):
        waypoint = waypoint.next(6)[0]
        waypoints.append(waypoint.transform.location)


    return waypoints

 # Function to transform CARLA's 3D world coordinates to 2D screen coordinates


 def world_to_screen(world_location, vehicle_transform, scale=0.5):
    # Relative coordinates
    # x_rel = world_location.x - vehicle_transform.location.x
    # y_rel = world_location.y - vehicle_transform.location.y
    
    # # Take into account the height of the camera on the car
    # z_rel = world_location.z - vehicle_transform.location.z

    x_rel = vehicle_transform.location.x
    y_rel =  vehicle_transform.location.y
    
    # Take into account the height of the camera on the car
    z_rel = vehicle_transform.location.z
    
    # Rotate to vehicle's perspective
    yaw_rad = np.deg2rad(vehicle_transform.rotation.yaw)
    x = x_rel * np.cos(yaw_rad) + y_rel * np.sin(yaw_rad)
    y = -x_rel * np.sin(yaw_rad) + y_rel * np.cos(yaw_rad)
    
    # Adjust for the camera's height (assuming the camera's height is around 1.5 meters from the ground)
    y -= z_rel - 1.5
    
    # Transform to screen space
    screen_x = 800 // 2 + int(x * scale)
    screen_y = 600 - int(y * scale)
    return screen_x, screen_y






 def draw_waypoints_on_pygame_display(waypoints, vehicle_transform, display):
    for waypoint in waypoints:
        screen_x, screen_y = world_to_screen(waypoint, vehicle_transform)
        # pygame.draw.circle(display, (0, 255, 0), (vehicle_transform.location.x,vehicle_transform.location.y), 5)
        pygame.draw.line(display,(0, 223, 222),(vehicle_transform.location.x,vehicle_transform.location.y),(screen_x,screen_y),6)
        print(f"screen_projection = {screen_x} ::: vehicle_location = {vehicle.get_location()}")
              



 vehicle = spawn_vehicle()

 camera = CameraManager(vehicle, hud, display)
 camera.transform_index = 0  # Choose the index of the camera transform
 camera.set_sensor(0)
 # Main loop
 while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    camera.render(display)
    waypoints = get_waypoints_ahead(vehicle)

    print(f"WayPoints_x-->{waypoints} ")

    draw_waypoints_on_pygame_display(
        waypoints, vehicle.get_transform(), display)
    
    vehicle.set_autopilot(True)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

any idea or help to do it